# Calculate Correlation with measurements and status

Tags: correlation

I have to calculate the correlation between measurements of some data.

If i have data for example body weight and size

```
170     60
177     66
188     90
```

etc

I know how to calculate a correlation and how to interpret this.

Now I have data which looks like this

```
170     -1
177     2
188     -1
190     -1
192     -2
```

second column is some kind of status.
I have to calculate the correlation between the measurements and the status. Any help how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

As long as there are only two statuses, you could calculate an ordinary correlation in the usual fashion (i.e. by treating those status values as numbers - it doesn't matter what the numbers are, as long as they're distinct, though you can flip the sign of the measure if you shift which one is coded with the larger value). That's one possible measure of association between a interval variable and a binary variable.

If there are multiple statuses* then you would need to clarify what, exactly, you mean by "correlation" in that situation.

* (or you intend a different way of measuring the relationship than the one implied by using the ordinary correlation with two statuses)